# Reading file using Cordova File Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, filereader, phonegap

I'm using cordova file plugin - [cordova file plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

I'm actually reading the file from the textfile. Below is my code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {  
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "sameple.txt", gotFile, fail);
}, true);

function gotFile(file) {           
    file.file(function (file) {                
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {          
            console.log(this.result);
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);                
    }, fail());            
}

function fail(e) {
    console.info("FileSystem Error : " + e);
}
```

So whenever i run this code, i'm getting the below error

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

Could not get Cordova FileSystem: Error: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
   "Could not get Cordova FileSystem:"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.",
      message: "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.",
      name: "Error"
   }

{"data":"data"}
```

After `deviceready error` later i'm able to get the exact data.. How do i resolve this error? do i have to wait for the device ready execution to complete?

Comment: Have you include cordova.js file in your source file?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can happen for a number of reasons, see [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/259) more details.

You should try firs [@bayanAbuawad suggestion](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/259#issuecomment-261205516) that works most of the times:

1. Add the platforms with cordova platform add ios android
2. Remove them with cordova platform remove ios android
3. Add them again.

It is super weird, but it’s related to a faulty android.json and ios.json inside the platforms folder.